# Rust closure errors -> ...which is owned by the current function | capture of moved value:

Tags: rust, gtk-rs

This code:

```
//let seen_cell = std::cell::RefCell::new(window_0);
window_0.connect_delete_event(|_, _| {

    //window_0.destroy();
    window.hide();
    Inhibit(true)  
    });

button_0.connect_clicked(|_|{  
    window.show_all(); 
    }  
);
```

Produces the errors:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `window`, which is owned by the current function
   --> src/main.rs:192:36
    |
192 |     window_0.connect_delete_event( |_, _| {
    |                                    ^^^^^^ may outlive borrowed value `window`
...
195 |         window.hide();
    |         ------ `window` is borrowed here
    |
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `window` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword, as shown:
    |     window_0.connect_delete_event( move |_, _| {

error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `window`, which is owned by the current function
   --> src/main.rs:199:30
    |
199 |     button_0.connect_clicked(|_|{
    |                              ^^^ may outlive borrowed value `window`
200 |         window.show_all();
    |         ------ `window` is borrowed here
    |
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `window` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword, as shown:
    |     button_0.connect_clicked(move |_|{
```

If I try this:

```
//let seen_cell = std::cell::RefCell::new(window_0);
window_0.connect_delete_event(move |_, _| {

    //window_0.destroy();
    window.hide();
    Inhibit(true)  
    });

button_0.connect_clicked(|_|{  
    window.show_all(); 
    }  
);
```

I get the errors:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `window`, which is owned by the current function
   --> src/main.rs:199:30
    |
199 |     button_0.connect_clicked(|_|{
    |                              ^^^ may outlive borrowed value `window`
200 |         window.show_all();
    |         ------ `window` is borrowed here
    |
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `window` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword, as shown:
    |     button_0.connect_clicked(move |_|{

error[E0382]: capture of moved value: `window`
   --> src/main.rs:199:30
    |
192 |     window_0.connect_delete_event(move |_, _| {
    |                                   ----------- value moved (into closure) here
...
199 |     button_0.connect_clicked(|_|{
    |                              ^^^ value captured here after move
    |
    = note: move occurs because `window` has type `gtk::Window`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

If I try this:

```rust
//let seen_cell = std::cell::RefCell::new(window_0);
window_0.connect_delete_event(move |_, _| {

    //window_0.destroy();
    window.hide();
    Inhibit(true)  
    });

button_0.connect_clicked(move|_|{  
    window.show_all(); 
    }  
);
```

I get the errors:

```
error[E0382]: capture of moved value: `window`
   --> src/main.rs:200:9
    |
192 |     window_0.connect_delete_event(move |_, _| {
    |                                   ----------- value moved (into closure) here
...
200 |         window.show_all();
    |         ^^^^^^ value captured here after move
    |
    = note: move occurs because `window` has type `gtk::Window`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I have read similar questions but I have not been able to solve this case. How can I solve this in the best way, perhaps by using `Arc` or similar?

Comment: The error is related to the lifetime of `window`, which you don't show. More context is necessary.

Comment: More specifically, you're trying to do something with the closure that could result in calling `window.hide()` *after* `window` has been destroyed, and similarly with the other closure for `window.show_all()`. You need to somehow prove to the compiler that those methods will only be called while `window` is still alive.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the above using a macro that I have drawn from some sample projects of gtk-rs

```
macro_rules! clone {
        (@param _) => ( _ );
        (@param $x:ident) => ( $x );
        ($($n:ident),+ => move || $body:expr) => (
            {
                $( let $n = $n.clone(); )+
                move || $body
            }
        );
        ($($n:ident),+ => move |$($p:tt),+| $body:expr) => (
            {
                $( let $n = $n.clone(); )+
                move |$(clone!(@param $p),)+| $body
            }
        );
    }
```

---

Taking the case described I have used it this way:

```
window_0.connect_delete_event(clone!(window => move |_, _| {

//window_0.destroy();
window.hide();
Inhibit(true)  
}));

button_0.connect_clicked(clone!(window => move |_|{  
    window.show_all(); 

}));
```

This is the relevant part `window_0.connect_delete_event(clone!(window => move`. In my case it also applies to `button_0.connect_clicked` because `window` Is used later in a similar place

Comment: Maybe you don't need the complexity of the `clone!` macro, you only need to clone `window` before accessing it, which is fairly standard in Rust. E.g. `window_0.connect_delete_event({let window = window.clone(); move |_, _| { ... }});` Not much more code than using `clone!`, and potentially clearer to the reader not familiar with the macro.